# Avoid the Meta Viewport Tag in Responsive Design - Google Insights Score

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, seo

I have designed my site to be responsive without actually using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It looks just the way I want it on mobile. The problem is, when I go to Google Insights, which to test if my site is mobile optimized, it says it is not. When I add the meta tag, it says my site is mobile optimized (even though it looks a lot worse to a human being).

My question is, can get around using the meta viewport tag while still having Google Insights tell me my site is mobile optimized and therefore adding that SEO benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be setting the viewport width to a specific size. This will make all devices view it as that set size.

Change it to 'device-width' like below and it will size to the devices width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: That still messes up my site. I tried a whole bunch of settings and nothing worked except not using it at all. As a point of reference,  the site where I'm having the issue is http://ninjawarrior.info/revamp/lifestyle.html

Comment: First thing I can see that could be it is the page scrolls horizontally. This might be a width that is fixed and too big. Try to remove all fixed widths that are putting it out.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap which had a lot of settings so it will be really hard to pinpoint the issue. I think it has something to do with the class container, but I removed all fixed widths. Since I have the page exactly the way I want it without the meta viewport tage, what I would really like to do is be able to not have to use it at all, but not be marked as non-responsive.