# Can I Rely on Automatic Mobile Adjustments for Responsive Design

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a website that I am trying to design to be responsive on mobile. Without doing much responsive styling, I actually like the way it looks on mobile. I read that mobile phones automatically make certain adjustments to websites to make them more compatible with mobile devices. I am pretty certain that is what mobile devices are doing with my site.

My question is, if I am content with the way my site looks on mobile without doing much responsive design, is it not necessary to do any further design. Can I rely on the mobile phones to ensure my site is reponsive? If it is better to do all of my own responsive styling, how important is it that I add responsive styling immediately?

**Note:** I am referring to that way my site looks on mobile without the meta viewport tag. When I add that tag, the mobile adjustements go away and I encounter some issues with my own styling (but I have a whole [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188428/avoid-the-meta-viewport-tag-in-responsive-design-google-insights-score/29188618) devoted to that). Also, I am looking at my site primarily using my Samsung Galaxy S4 using the Google Chrome browser. I did do certain responsive styling, but not a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is what the design looks like on your mobile phone specifically then no, you wouldn't need to design any further.

However, you should take into consideration what it might look like for other users with different devices and device widths.

It is best practice to use the meta viewport tag to work across all devices and allow your site to be truly responsive.

Is your site mobile friendly?  Try using Google's mobile friendly test: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Google is updating their search algorithms to place a higher importance on a site being mobile friendly.  If it is not your site will not rank as high in their search index.  Read more about it here:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/02/finding-more-mobile-friendly-search.html

Comment: I've actually been having an issue, and this is addressed in my second question where google says my site is mobile friendly only when I use the meta viewport tag. However, the site looks a lot worse with the meta viewport tag. Do mobile phone responsive adjustments vary or do they all  use the same practice?

Comment: In practice all "modern" mobile browsers will act the same.  It's the devices specific width and orientation that will differer between devices.  Even though it may sound like a pain to add the meta viewport tag into your site and modify the code so that it works properly, you and your users will greatly benefit from doing so.

Comment: If browsers "act" the same, I think the only real benefit is Google viewing my site as responsive. I'm hoping to get around that because it will take a lot of effort to design my site if I use the meta viewport tag.